# Can't figure out why jest testing giving me old state after click fireEvent

Tags: typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, apollo-client

I'm using Jest and @testing-library/react while mocking data with MockedProvider from @apollo/client/testing. While trying to figure out how to changes that occurs with click, I found this really strange behaviour with this test:

```
  test('Test 1', async () => {
    mockAllIsIntersecting(true);
    renderTest(() => (
      <MockedApolloProvider
        mocks={[
          getProductMock({ code: '7340266_F671' }),
          appSettingsSalesDocumentMock(),
        ]}
      >
        <ProductCard
          product={productMock}
          language="no"
          translated={translatedMock}
        />
      </MockedApolloProvider>
    ));

    fireEvent.click(await screen.findByTitle('A'));
    const img = screen.getByAltText(
      'B',
    );
    console.log(img);
    expect(img.getAttribute('src')).toEqual(
      'C',
    );
  });
```

1. first of all the click event is suppose to change an Image (to image 2)
2. The link (a-href tag with preventDefault) to change image is found by searching for "A"
3. then I do a fireEvent.click on it
4. It should fetch the mocked data from MockedApolloProvider
5. The image 1 should have changed source now, but when i try to find image 2 in my console the image is still the old image 1.

But the strange thing is that if i change the getByAltText('B') where B is something else not in the DOM, the test prints out that it didn't match and what the available DOM looks like which is now suddenly the one with the correct Image (image 2).

it looks like when screen.getByAltText('B') is succesfully found, the click event get reverted???

heres the Veery simplified version of the component im using, tried to included the important/relevant parts:

```
export const ProductCard: React.FC<ProductCardProps> = memo(
  ({ product }) => {
    const [productState, setProductState] = useState(product);
    const currProduct = productState;
    const { code, url, siblings } = currProduct;

    const loadProduct = (productCode: string) => {
      getProduct({
        variables: { variantCode: productCode },
        onCompleted: (data) => {
          data.getProduct && setProductState(data.getProduct);
        },
      });
    };
    const onSiblingClick = (
      productCode: string,
      event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>,
    ) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (currProduct.code === productCode) {
        return false;
      }
      loadProduct(productCode);
    };

    return (
      <ProductCardContainer>
        <ProductCardImageContainer>
          <ProductCardHoverElements
            currProduct={currProduct}
            product={product}
          />
        </ProductCardImageContainer>
        {/* onSiblingClick gets triggered in the test*/}
        <ProductColors
          code={code}
          productUrl={url}
          siblings={siblings}
          onSiblingClick={onSiblingClick}
          numberOfVisibleSwatches={3}
          size="small"
          ariaLabelMoreColors="More colors"
        />
      </ProductCardContainer>
    );
  },
  (prevProps, nextProps) => {
    return prevProps.product.code === nextProps.product.code;
  },
);
```

NOTE: both the image 1 and image 2 has the same "B" alt-text

NOTE2: screen.findByTitle('A') is a hyperlink (a-href) with a clickHandler in the component

Comment: Could you also share the component you are testing? maybe something asynchronous happens. You are waiting for 'A' to become visible. But then not waiting for the image to change. Maybe you have to await the rerender. Or await the fireEvent (by putting it inside `await act(async() => {//FireEvent here}))`

Comment: i get "Avoid wrapping Testing Library util calls in `act`" from my ESLint when i try to wrap the fireEvent around a act. And my Component is Reaaaaly big i don't know if you wanna have a look at it hehe 220 line-component

Comment: No, we don't, but we do need a [mre] of it.

Comment: I see, by the way wrapping the fireEvent.click with act worked, but Its not recommended to wrap it since it fireEvent arleady is wrapped? doesnt make sense?

Comment: I've seen those kinds of unexpected act warning when there are two versions of `@testing-library/dom` in play, e.g. via `/react` and `/user-event`, could that be the situation here?

Comment: hmm i have     "@testing-library/dom": "^9.3.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you shouldn't wrap fireEvent in act is that it is redundant, since fireEvent is already wrapped in act. However, there is an importent distinction here. You are not just wrapping fireEvent in act, but you are wrapping it in an asynchronous act and awaiting it:

```
await act(async() => {
  await fireEvent.click('somthing');
})
```

This is different from the normal act that fireEvent is wrapped in and shouldn't get a complaint from esLint. You can see the different types in the type definitions:

```
// VoidOrUndefinedOnly is here to forbid any sneaky "Promise" returns.
// the actual return value is always a "DebugPromiseLike".
declare const UNDEFINED_VOID_ONLY: unique symbol;
// tslint:disable-next-line: void-return
type VoidOrUndefinedOnly = void | { [UNDEFINED_VOID_ONLY]: never };
/**
 * Wrap any code rendering and triggering updates to your components into `act()` calls.
 *
 * Ensures that the behavior in your tests matches what happens in the browser
 * more closely by executing pending `useEffect`s before returning. This also
 * reduces the amount of re-renders done.
 *
 * @param callback An asynchronous, void callback that will execute as a single, complete React commit.
 *
 * @see https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html#testing-hooks
 */
// VoidOrUndefinedOnly is here to forbid any sneaky return values
export function act(callback: () => Promise<VoidOrUndefinedOnly>): Promise<undefined>;
/**
 * Wrap any code rendering and triggering updates to your components into `act()` calls.
 *
 * Ensures that the behavior in your tests matches what happens in the browser
 * more closely by executing pending `useEffect`s before returning. This also
 * reduces the amount of re-renders done.
 *
 * @param callback A synchronous, void callback that will execute as a single, complete React commit.
 *
 * @see https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html#testing-hooks
 */
export function act(callback: () => VoidOrUndefinedOnly): DebugPromiseLike;

// Intentionally doesn't extend PromiseLike<never>.
// Ideally this should be as hard to accidentally use as possible.
export interface DebugPromiseLike {
    // the actual then() in here is 1-ary, but that doesn't count as a PromiseLike.
    then(onfulfilled: (value: never) => never, onrejected: (reason: never) => never): never;
}
```

Instead of wrapping fireEvent in async act you can often also use a waitFor around the expect that comes after it. I slightly prefer this now.

```
    fireEvent.click(await screen.findByTitle('A'));
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByAltText('B').getAttribute('src')).toEqual('C');
    })
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, wrapping waitFor around expect worked